# Pass array of form element using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and I need to pass it to PHP page
this is my HTML part ,

```
 for ($j=0;$j<2;$j++) {
        ?>

        <tr><th><div class="col-xs-2">


                    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Time[]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;">

                    </div></td>
        <?php   
        for ($s=1;$s<=count($days)-6;$s++) {
            ?>
            <td><div class="col-xs-2">

                    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Subject[]"  id="Subject<?php echo $j.$s ?>" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;"> 
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Day[]" id="inputlg" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $days[$s]; ?>" style="width:120px; height:30px;">

                    </div></td>
            <?php   
        }
        echo "</tr>";


    }
```

and this is my jquery code ,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        var Sub = $('[name=Subject]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sample.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'Subject=' + Sub,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("ERRRR");
            }

        })
    });
});
```

and this is my PHP code ,

```
     $Sub  = $_POST['Subject'];
     print_r($Sub);
```

It actually sending the value but I don't get any response. I am stucking with it any help will be really appreciated .

**EDIT :**

I have heared map or each function can do this but I dont know how to use the functions

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: No it show me succes alert, Status 200 OK

Comment: Do you see the data passed to server in network request

Comment: @Tushar I have array of Subjects like Subjects[0],Subjects[1] ....... I need to send all these that what the problem . I can send a single value by this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($j=0;$j<2;$j++) {
    ?>
    <form>
    <tr><th><div class="col-xs-2">


                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Time[]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;">

                </div></td>
    <?php   
    for ($s=1;$s<=count($days)-6;$s++) {
        ?>
        <td><div class="col-xs-2">

               <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Subject[]"  id="Subject<?php echo $j.$s ?>" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;"> 
                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Day[]" id="inputlg" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $days[$s]; ?>" style="width:120px; height:30px;">

                </div>
         </td>

        <?php   
    }
    echo "</tr>";


} ?>

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="sub">
</form>
```

And Script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'newpage.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: str,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("ERRRR");
        }

    })
});
```

});

Using this you will get whole inputs array.

Comment: thnx that what exactly I wanted